# Как преобразовать String[] к int[][]

Tags: java

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как преобразовать строчный массив чисел к двумерному числовому?

```
String[] strArray = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
int[][] intArray = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

Comment: А вы в курсе, что `String[] strArray` инициализирован неправильно, по факту у вас просто строка?

Comment: Нет, не в курсе, конечно. Яву знаю на уровне Hello World. Но задачу решить надо.

Comment: Отредактировал ваш код

Comment: Извините, запутал Вас. `String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"` Строка, а не массив. Но распарсить в массив символов могу с помощью .split()

Comment: Ну да. str.split(", "). Проверьте мой ответ :) Так? Я просто не имею под рукой IDE

Answer (score 1):

Без тестов

```
public int[][] foo (String[] strArray) {
    int bar = strArray.length / 3;
    if(strArray.length % 3 != 0) return null;
    int[][] d = new int[3][bar];
    int f = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < bar; x++) {
        String s = strArray[x];
        if(f != 2) f++;
        else f = 0;
        d[f][x] = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: 1) второй индекс при заполнении массива `d` должен меняться не от 0 до `strArray.length`, а от 0 до `strArray.length / 3` 2) не учтена ситуация с длиной исходного массива не кратной 3

Comment: А есть ли что-то совсем простое вроде `eval()` в Питоне?

Comment: @Skotinin, питон не Java. Если есть что-то проще - поделитесь.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Main.parseToArray(Main.java:15)`

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменил и заработало.

```
int[][] d = new int[4][4];
        int f = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                String s = strArray[f];
                d[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(s);
                f++;
            }
        }
```